# How to use jQuery to horizontally center an object in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this was asked before, but my situation is somewhat... weird. I am building an iframe for later use in a slideshow element on the website.

I have a long content-adaptive flexbox that goes way beyond the screen and I want to use the css trick of

```
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

To horizontally center the *currently viewed* area of the page, so when you resize the window, the middle of ***currently viewed*** element, will still remain horizontally in the middle of the screen.

As my flexbox is content-adaptive it's like 5K px long so I obviously can't use css %. So I went to jQuery and used `$(window).width()` to determine current viewport size and adjust the elements with `.css({})` method. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).resize(function(){
var winWidthHalf = ($(window).width())/2;
$("#ss_home").css({
"left":"-"+winWidthHalf+"px",
"-webkit-transform":"translateX("+winWidthHalf+"px)"
});
});
});
```

And here's the puzzle: it worked. And then I restarted the PC and it didn't work since. Whatever I did didn't seem to help. Can you help? I have NO idea what could have happened...
Here is the page preview, please don't mind other comments in the code, they are irrelevant for now: http://users.metropolia.fi/~staniss/test/slideshow/

All content is just sample.

I would also love to know how to group the `$(document).ready` and `$(window).resize` properly, since I execute the same code, but don't wanna copy paste it twice just to change the events, since that's a bad practice. I haven't been able to find the right syntax for this.

Also sorry, the sample is for chrome only, it's very early in dev so I didn't bother with compatibility yet.

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong with your sample

Comment: Nobody else can? Really? Damn...

Comment: Why don't you just explain what the problem is?  A graphical example or a video may help.

Comment: I think my explanation is quite clear. I want the element that's in the middle to stay centered when the window is resized. Go to sample URL, scroll somewhere and try to resize the window. You will see that it just reveals/crops more area to the right of the screen instead of equally adjusting the page from both sides in respect to what was originally in the viewport center. Same thing as you'd do with CSS, as described here: http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser vendor extension issue (had to add -webkit- prefix to transform) :P.